# Speech recognition API Chrome IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, webspeech-api, chrome-ios

I am trying to implement speech recognition/synthesis is a web app using Chrome. My app works great in Mac/Win, but not on IOS. I hear conflicting things about IOS support.

Is the speech API working for Chrome IOS?
If so, is there any special things you need to do to program or use it?

Here is the app: https://viseyes.org/liza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported for iOS Chrome at this time. Per [the Web Speech API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API#Browser_support), "Support for Web Speech API speech recognition is curently limited to Chrome for Desktop and Android — Chrome has supported it since around version 33 but with prefixed interfaces, so you need to include prefixed versions of them, e.g. webkitSpeechRecognition."